# clang-format multiple BasedOnStyle for multiple Language

Tags: llvm, clang-format

In the `clang-format` [documentation](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html), you can set the default options for `clang-format` by creating a file named `.clang-format`.

And the syntax provided in the doc is as follows:

```
---
# We'll use defaults from the LLVM style, but with 4 columns indentation.
BasedOnStyle: LLVM
IndentWidth: 4
---
Language: Cpp
# Force pointers to the type for C++.
DerivePointerAlignment: false
PointerAlignment: Left
---
Language: JavaScript
# Use 100 columns for JS.
ColumnLimit: 100
---
Language: Proto
# Don't format .proto files.
DisableFormat: true
---
Language: CSharp
# Use 100 columns for C#.
ColumnLimit: 100
...
```

However, when I try applying `BasedOnStyle` variable to individual `Language` as below:

```
Language: C
BasedOnStyle: LLVM

Language: Cpp
BasedOnStyle: LLVM

Language: Java
BasedOnStyle: Google

Language: JavaScript
BasedOnStyle: Google
```

it does not seem to work.

The question is

1. Is it possible to use different `BasedOnStyle` for different languages?
2. If so, how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the `BasedOnStyle` only defines styles for `Language: Cpp`.

This can be shown by the following command:

```
clang-format -style=llvm -dump-config
```

The above command outputs styles that succeed `Language: Cpp`. The same goes for other values of `BasedOnStyle`.

So if `BasedOnStyle` is succeeded by `Language` key and a value other than `Cpp`, `clang-format` will fail.

Hence, it is not possible to apply different predefined styles (`LLVM`, `Google`, etc.) to different languages.